# Cannot scaffold Asp.net core controller with view for class that inherit IdentityUser

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

i have a `User` class in my application

```
    public class User
    {
        [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(10)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [MinLength(3), MaxLength(10)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(10)]
        public string LastNmae { get; set; }

    }
```

then i try to scaffold controller with view for this class, the drop down for model class included the User class and other classes that extend it such as `Student` and `Admin`

[image]

Then i make the `User` class inherit `IdentityUser` class

```
    public class User: IdentityUser
    {
        [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(10)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [MinLength(3), MaxLength(10)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required, MinLength(3), MaxLength(10)]
        public string LastNmae { get; set; }

    }
```

And then try to scaffold controller and view for the `User` class again, now the drop down for model class no longer included the User class and other classes that extend it

[image]

What is wrong